# how to form submit with parameters and headers for oauth2 authorization server?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, thymeleaf

Here I am using the ajax call and get the access token.How to get access token without using ajax call? Anyone can help me.
Authorization server created using spring boot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"            
 xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/web/thymeleaf/layout"
 layout:decorator="maintemplate">
<head>
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">        </script>-->
    <title>Spring Security Example </title>
</head>
<body>

    <div layout:fragment="bodyContent">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <label>Username</label><input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
        <label>Password</label><input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
        <div class="portlet-filters">
            <div>
                <button type="button" style="margin-top: 10px; " class="btn btn-sm btn-primary form-control" th:onclick="'search()'">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div layout:fragment="scripts">
        <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
            function search() {
                var username = $('#username').val();
                var password = $('#password').val();
                var encoded = btoa("foo:foosecret");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/authservice/oauth/token",
                    data: {grant_type: 'password', username: username, password: password},
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "Basic " + encoded,
                        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        alert("Data Saved: ");
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following...I changed some stuff so it doesn't refer to my urls, but works for my auth server I wrote:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://site.auth.com/oauth/token"> <!--layout:fragment="bodyContent" depth-->
    <div class="container">        
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="grant_type" value="code_authenticate">
      <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="XEeJYNqbZT_mIra2qJrh-ibkU-8xbyYnRQUFDZy5">
      <input type="hidden" name="response_type" value="code">
      <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="https://site.client.com">
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Very helpful answer! This made my day! Spent almost 3 hrs messing up with Oauth2 and thymleaf and this did the trick!. Actualy when definge the action as `th:action="${url}"` always prompts the basic auth windows in browser and this did the trick. Kudos!